# How do I get this to detect a win?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on getting this terminal game (tic tac toe) to detect a win but I'm not too sure how to go about it. I need the game to pass the node test. I've tried a few different things but haven't been able to get anything to work. I need the remaining code to be placed in "function checkForWin" for this to work.

```
'use strict';

const assert = require('assert');
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
let board = [
  [' ', ' ', ' '],
  [' ', ' ', ' '],
  [' ', ' ', ' ']
];

let playerTurn = 'X';

function printBoard() {
  console.log('   0  1  2');
  console.log('0 ' + board[0].join(' | '));
  console.log('  ---------');
  console.log('1 ' + board[1].join(' | '));
  console.log('  ---------');
  console.log('2 ' + board[2].join(' | '));
}

function horizontalWin() {
  if (
      board [0] [0] === playerTurn && 
      board [0] [1] === playerTurn &&
      board [0] [2] === playerTurn
      ) {
        return true;
      } else if (
        board [1] [0] === playerTurn && 
        board [1] [1] === playerTurn &&
        board [1] [2] === playerTurn 
      ) {
        return true;
      } else if (
        board [2] [0] === playerTurn && 
        board [2] [1] === playerTurn &&
        board [2] [2] === playerTurn 
      ) {
        return true;
      } 
        return false;


}

function verticalWin() {

  if (
    board [0] [0] === playerTurn && 
    board [1] [0] === playerTurn &&
    board [2] [0] === playerTurn
    ) {
      return true;
    } else if (
      board [0] [1] === playerTurn && 
      board [1] [1] === playerTurn &&
      board [2] [1] === playerTurn 
    ) {
      return true;
    } else if (
      board [0] [2] === playerTurn && 
      board [1] [2] === playerTurn &&
      board [2] [2] === playerTurn 
    ) {
      return true;
    } 
      return false;
}

function diagonalWin() {

  if (
    board [0] [0] === playerTurn && 
    board [1] [1] === playerTurn &&
    board [2] [2] === playerTurn
    ) {
      return true;
    } else if (
      board [0] [2] === playerTurn && 
      board [1] [1] === playerTurn &&
      board [2] [0] === playerTurn 
    ) {
      return true;
    } 
      return false;
}

function checkForWin() {


}

function ticTacToe(row, column) {

  let selectedRow = board[row];
  selectedRow[column] = playerTurn;

  if (playerTurn === 'X') {
    playerTurn = 'O';
  } else if (playerTurn === 'O') {
    playerTurn = 'X';
  }



}

function getPrompt() {
  printBoard();
  console.log("It's Player " + playerTurn + "'s turn.");
  rl.question('row: ', (row) => {
    rl.question('column: ', (column) => {
      ticTacToe(row, column);
      getPrompt();
    });
  });

}



// Tests

if (typeof describe === 'function') {

  describe('#ticTacToe()', () => {
    it('should place mark on the board', () => {
      ticTacToe(1, 1);
      assert.deepEqual(board, [ [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'X', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '] ]);
    });
    it('should alternate between players', () => {
      ticTacToe(0, 0);
      assert.deepEqual(board, [ ['O', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'X', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '] ]);
    });
    it('should check for vertical wins', () => {
      board = [ [' ', 'X', ' '], [' ', 'X', ' '], [' ', 'X', ' '] ];
      assert.equal(verticalWin(), true);
    });
    it('should check for horizontal wins', () => {
      board = [ ['X', 'X', 'X'], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '] ];
      assert.equal(horizontalWin(), true);
    });
    it('should check for diagonal wins', () => {
      board = [ ['X', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'X', ' '], [' ', ' ', 'X'] ];
      assert.equal(diagonalWin(), true);
    });
    it('should detect a win', () => {
      assert.equal(checkForWin(), true);
    });
  });
} else {

  getPrompt();

}
```